# How can I locally cancel all the changes made in a commit?

Tags: git, github

I have a specific directory where the sources where modified in a specific commit `0x0x0x0x0`. After that commit have been many other commits all on the master.

I want to cancel that commit `0x0x0x0x0` and locally(not upstream) in this specific directory have the code prior to  when this commit was made. 
What git commands can I run for this?

***Later edit***: I want just that specific commit canceled not the subsequent changes. As code it doesn't affect me since it is an independent module. Also I will not use this local repository for committing further upstream.

Comment: `git checkout abcdef^` will locally get you to the parent of that commit. This will however detach your local code and make doing anything upstream later difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to go back to before the commit was introduced, so effectively removing its changes and all changes that happened afterwards (in other commits), you can do the following:

- Check out a new branch to the old version, so you don’t lose any information but can just restart from the old state: `git checkout -b <newbranchname> commithash~1`
- Reset your current branch to the old version, effectively removing all the commits from the history if no other branch points to them: `git reset --hard commithash~1`

But if you just want to undo said commit while keeping all the changes that were made afterwards, you can just do this:

```
git revert commithash
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to return to any commit with the following command:

`git reset --hard commit_identifier`

Note: to obtain the commit identifier use `git log` command

You can also reset the last commit with command:

`git commit --amend`

Take a look to the next link for more information:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html